# Performing en edit on a record in a store

Tags: extjs

If I have a record, which belongs to -a- store, but without knowledge of -which- store it belongs to, how do I delete that record?

Eg

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model:'Pies'
    data:{Type:123,Name:"apple"}
})

var record = store.getAt(0)
//How do I store.remove(record); without actually having the store record handy?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your record will actually have property `.store` which you can use to reference store it belongs to - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-property-store

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Ext JS code that removes a given record.  The record has a reference to the store it belongs to.  Using that store reference combined with the store's remove method, you can remove the record as coded below.

Run the code pasted below here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MSXdg/

The example code:

```
Ext.define('Pies', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'Type',
        'Name'
    ]
})

var pieData = [{
    Type:123,
    Name:'apple'
}];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model:'Pies',
    data: pieData, 
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    }
})

var debug = Ext.fly('debug');

if (debug) {
    debug.setHTML('Record count: ' + store.getCount());
}
console.log('Record count: ' + store.getCount())

var record = store.getAt(0);

// remove the record
record.store.remove(record);

// display the store count to confirm removal
if (debug) {
    debug.setHTML(debug.getHTML() + '<br />Record count after removal: ' + store.getCount());
}
console.log('Record count after removal: ', store.getCount())
```

​